# truffle migrate fails when I remove console.log

Tags: web3js, truffle-deployment

I have this migration script:

```
var MyTok = artifacts.require("./MyTok.sol")
var MyTok_Crowdfund = artifacts.require('./MyTok_Crowdfund.sol')

module.exports = function (deployer, _, accounts) {

    var kycSigner = [],
        wallet = accounts[1],
        startTime = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp,
        endTime = startTime + (86400 * 30), //30 days
        price = 18000

    // console.log("DEBUG: \nstart Time: " + startTime + "\nend Time: " + endTime)
    deployer.deploy(MyTok).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(MyTok_Crowdfund, kycSigner, MyTok.address, 
          wallet, price, startTime, endTime)
    })
}
```

Which does not work, unless I **uncomment** the `console.log` line.
This suggest me I should somewhat *wait* for the `web3.eth.getBlock` call, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Can you tell what version of web3.js and Truffle you are using ?

Comment: Truffle v4.1.12 (core: 4.1.12)

Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)

web3 version: 0.20.6

Comment: what is the purpose of `_` in `module.exports = function (deployer, _, accounts)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [the documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblock) and as you suggested, there's a callback parameter in which you can call your log.

Example call is :

> web3.eth.getBlock(3150)
>   .then(console.log);

Comment: But I don't want to call my log, it is there for debugging purposes.
And as I said, the problem is if I remove that log, there won't be any deployment.

At this moment, on `truffle` I get: `truffle(localGanache)> web3.eth.getBlock('latest').then(console.log)
TypeError: web3.eth.getBlock(...).then is not a function`